# Tube model imported from Blender getting stretched vertically when rendering

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders, geometry

I'm actually working on a 3D game engine with OpenGL 4 and C++. The problem is that, I don't know why, my geometry isn't well renderered except for primitives.

[image: Example]

At the right you can see a cube, it is rendered as intended.
At the center you can see a mesh that I've made in blender, it is not rendered as intended, at the left you can see my mesh rendered as intended BUT I did tweak the Z-Scale (and I should not do that)

So to be short : My mesh are not rendered well proportionned.

I verified coordinates of each vertices in blender and my project : they're same.

I don't know if there is a problem with my matrices, the only thing I know is that problem appears only on the Z-Axis (Z is up).

Everything let me think that somewhere a number is rounded but I can't see where

I leave here some code, which might be helpful :

Mesh Rendering Code :

```c
void RD_Mesh::render(RenderMode rndrMode) {
    if (rndrMode == RenderMode::Filled) {
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    }
    else {
        glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
    }

    //m_shader->useShader();
    m_mat->BindMaterial();

    glm::mat4 mdl = glm::mat4(1.0f); //Declaring Model Matrix

    glm::mat4 translate = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 scale = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    glm::mat4 rotation = glm::mat4(1.0f);

    //Position
    translate = glm::translate(translate, glm::vec3(m_position.getX(), m_position.getY(), m_position.getZ()));

    //Scale
    scale = glm::scale(scale, glm::vec3(m_scale.getX(), m_scale.getY(), m_scale.getZ()));

    //Rotation
    rotation = glm::rotate(rotation, glm::radians(m_rotation.getX()), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    rotation = glm::rotate(rotation, glm::radians(m_rotation.getY()), glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    rotation = glm::rotate(rotation, glm::radians(m_rotation.getZ()), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f));

    mdl = translate * rotation * scale;

    m_shader->SetMatrix("model", mdl);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, RAWindices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
}
```

Camera code :

```c
void RD_Camera::SetupCamera() {
    projection = glm::perspective(glm::radians(FOV), (float)m_rndr->getWindowWidth() / m_rndr->getWindowHeigh(), m_near, m_far); //Projection matrix

    view = glm::lookAt(glm::vec3(m_pos.getX(), m_pos.getY(), m_pos.getZ()), glm::vec3(m_subject.getX(), m_subject.getY(), m_subject.getZ()), glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)); //View matrix

    m_rndr->GetCurrentShader()->SetMatrix("projection", projection);
    m_rndr->GetCurrentShader()->SetMatrix("view", view);
    m_rndr->GetCurrentShader()->SetVec3("CamPos", m_pos);
}
```

My Vertex Shader:

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec3 aNormal;

out vec3 Normal;
out vec3 FragPos;

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 model;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(aPos, 1.0);

    Normal = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(model))) * aNormal);
    FragPos = vec3(model * vec4(aPos, 1.0));
}
```

Comment: what are the values of m_scale?

Comment: @ratchetfreak for the cube it is (0.5, 0.5, 0.5), for the middle mesh it is (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) and the corrected mesh (1.0, 1.0, 0.3)

Comment: @Vektorweg I'm sure, I exported the cube as the same way as the mesh, and every scalar parameters were at 1.0

Comment: When you export your object in obj and you open it as text, are the vertices where they should?

Comment: @Vaillancourt I don't use obj, I export everything in fbx, but I've already checked that. Every vertices are where they must be, they're the same between blender and FBX

Comment: @Vaillancourt Also, I have my own file format, but vertices are the same as my FBX file and Blender file